# Python - Accepting string and passing as hex value to for displying on GPIO

Tags: python, int, hex

I am working on a raspberry pi project where i want to get an input from user and then display it on 8 segment LED display. below is the code:

---

```
pins = [11,12,13,15,16,18,22,7]
dats = [0x3f,0x06,0x5b,0x4f,0x66,0x6d,0x7d,0x07,0x7f,0x6f,0x77,0x7c,0x39,0x5e,0x79,0x71,0x80]

def setup():
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        for pin in pins:
                GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)   # Set pin mode as output
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)


def writeOneByte(val):
        print val
        GPIO.output(11, val & (0x01 << 0))
        print (val & (0x01 << 0))
        GPIO.output(12, val & (0x01 << 1))
        print (val & (0x01 << 1))
        GPIO.output(13, val & (0x01 << 2))
        print (val & (0x01 << 2))
        GPIO.output(15, val & (0x01 << 3))
        print (val & (0x01 << 3))
        GPIO.output(16, val & (0x01 << 4))
        print (val & (0x01 << 4))
        GPIO.output(18, val & (0x01 << 5))
        print (val & (0x01 << 5))
        GPIO.output(22, val & (0x01 << 6))
        print (val & (0x01 << 6))
        GPIO.output(7,  val & (0x01 << 7))
        print (val & (0x01 << 7))

def loop():  # ignore this loop fo now
        while True:
                for dat in dats:
                        writeOneByte(dat)
                        time.sleep(0.5)

def destroy():
        for pin in pins:
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.cleanup()             # Release resource

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
        setup()
        try:
            usernumber = input('Enter a number [0-9] to be displayed: ')
            usernumber = format(usernumber,'#04x')
            usernumber = str(usernumber)
            print 'The hex format is:',usernumber.strip()
            usernnumber = usernumber.strip()
            writeOneByte(usernumber)
            #writeOneByte(0xff)
            time.sleep(10)
            destroy()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:  # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the child program destroy() will be executed.
                destroy()
```

---

when i run the code and after i give it the input, i get an error:

```
Enter a number [0-9] to be displayed: 3
The hex format is: 0x03
0x03
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "9.segment_try.py", line 53, in <module>
    writeOneByte(usernumber)
  File "9.segment_try.py", line 17, in writeOneByte
    GPIO.output(11, val & (0x01 << 0))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I tried many things but i am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the input string value to an int type. Can do that via:

```
int(val, 0)
```

Ex:

```
val = "0x03"
int(val, 0)  # will return 3
```

Comment: Apologize for my formatting but here is what i am trying to achieve and the error i am getting    
    
    usernumber = input('Enter a number [0-9] to be displayed: ')
    usernumber = format(usernumber,'#04x')
    usernumber = str(usernumber)
    print 'The hex format is:',usernumber.strip()
    usernnumber = usernumber.strip()
    writeOneByte(usernumber)
    
    def writeOneByte(val):
            GPIO.output(11, val & (0x01 << 0))

    GPIO.output(11, val & (0x01 << 0))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: What is the type of val?

Comment: I think val should be hexadecimal. Like the line that I have commented out 'writeOneByte(0xff)', it works fine in the code. But if i accept a number and then convrt to hex and pass it to function, then i get the error.